# Is there an app than converts a screenshot of a diagram to tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics

I know that [Snip](https://snip.mathpix.com/) can convert a screenshot of text into latex formatting. I am wondering if there is an application that can convert a screenshot of a diagram into tikz formatting?

For example, is there any other way to convert this image into tikz instead of by hand?

[image]

Comment: The answer, actual, is no.

Comment: `\tikz{\node[inner sep=0pt]{\includegraphics{...}};}`

Comment: There is a possibly-obsolete list of TiKz GUI programs here https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26972/what-gui-applications-are-there-to-assist-in-generating-graphics-for-tex  Although they do not do what you asked, maybe you could load the screenshot as a background, and trace over it.

Comment: [GeoGebra](https://www.geogebra.org/classic#geometry) can export to PGF/TikZ

Comment: [graphics - Someway to export a hand (or tablet) sketch to tikz? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/636855/someway-to-export-a-hand-or-tablet-sketch-to-tikz); [How best to convert this poorly-scanned diagram to TikZ? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/599994/how-best-to-convert-this-poorly-scanned-diagram-to-tikz) (there are some solutions in one of the question there but they all require some manual work. Unfortunately it isn't possible to vote as duplicate of questions that does not have an answer)